# ASP.NET MVC3 ViewModel - Confused

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm learning about ViewModels in C# ASP.NET MVC 3, and I'm stuck at displaying data from the ViewModel in my View.

The **Models**:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index View I want to show general lists of both Authors and Books. I have made a **ViewModel** for this:

```
public class BookIndexViewModel
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my **Index() action method** from the controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        BookIndexViewModel viewModel = new BookIndexViewModel();
        viewModel.Authors = db.Authors.ToList();

        // leaving Books empty for now

        return View(viewModel);        
    }
```

I have a strongly typed **Index View** where I want to show the list of Authors:

```
@model IEnumerable<NewBookStore.ViewModels.BookIndexViewModel>

@foreach (var author in Model.Authors) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @author.Name
    </td>
</tr> 
}
```

It's the **Model.Authors** part that doesn't work. When I type Model. and wait for IntelliSense to show Authors, it isn't listed. The error description is:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'     does not contain a definition for 'Authors' and no extension method 'Authors' accepting a     first argument of type     'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could     be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: the model in the view shouldnt be IEnumerable. You are sending a single model which has 2 lists in it. You are not sending a list of viewmodels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the model in the view shouldnt be IEnumerable. You are sending a single model which has 2 lists in it. You are not sending a list of viewmodels.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe the solution was so simple. Always happens! :)

Comment: no problem :) Its always these small things u end up spending the most time on

Answer (score 0):

`@model IEnumerable<NewBookStore.ViewModels.BookIndexViewModel>` should be
`@model BookIndexViewModel` instead!

You don't want an `IEnumerable` of `BookIndexViewModel` - the Authors property is directly off your `BookIndexViewModel`.

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing a `collection` your View, You are passing only one object of `BookIndexViewModel` class from your action method.

To fix this, update your view to to bind it to only one instance instead of a `collection`

```
@model NewBookStore.ViewModels.BookIndexViewModel

@foreach (var author in Model.Authors)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @author.Name
    </td>
</tr> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finnayra,

Your error here is that you aren't defining the model correctly. Your model already holds the IEnumerable<> collections, so no need to make it Enumerable as well. Try:

```
@model NewBookStore.ViewModels.BookIndexViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
@model NewBookStore.ViewModels.BookIndexViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

[Note - I don't have enough exp to make this a comment rather than an answer!]

I was reading another article regarding ViewModels and from what @Darin Dimitrov was saying is that you should avoid putting Domain objects into your ViewModel,

"View models should not reference any services. View models should not reference any domain models."

see -> 
[ASP.NET MVC 3 Viewmodel Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553944/asp-net-mvc-3-viewmodel-pattern)

I know patterns are more like guides that don't fit every scenario but like the OP, I need to display a list of domain objects (books and authors we'll just say) so in the OP's example, should the ViewModel have?:

```
public class BookIndexViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Books { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Authors { get; set; }       
}
```

The BookIndexViewModel is then populated in your controller (which might use a service to get a list of Book and a list of Author to flatten into ViewModel) ??

I too am learning this stuff so open to suggestions/comments and corrections!! Thanks.