# How to provide a model to a nested view in MVC (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Suppose I'm rendering another page(view) to a page (view).
Now the nested view has its separate model. How to provide the model to the nested view.

Here is the example.

my Index Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.CreateModel = new Todo();
            return View(db.Todos.ToList());
        }
```

my Index View:

```
IEnumerable<ToDoMVC.Models.Todo>
@RenderPage("~/Views/Todo/Create.cshtml",ViewBag.CreateModel)
```

my Create View:

```
@model ToDoMVC.Models.Todo
// does operations with this model
```

Now, if I run the program it gives me some model type mismatch error for create view.

So, how to solve this? How to provide another model to a nested view from a view?

Answer (score 0):

In your model you would have a seperate model as a variable.

For example

```
  class Todo {
      public CreateModel create {get;set}
   }
```

Then when you pass through to the second view you would do something like this:

```
  @RenderPage("~/Views/Todo/Create.cshtml",Model.create)
```

That will pass that second model to your create page

**Edit**

Re-reading your question.

The mismatch will be because you are passing the whole model through and you want to pass an individual list item in.

So you need too loop through the model like this:

```
  foreach(var item in Model)
  {
      @RenderPage("~/Views/Todo/Create.cshtml", item)
  }
```

Comment: My model is like:
    `public class Todo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class TodoDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: And if I run the app in /create route everything works fine. What i want is to use the 'create' view inside some other view

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a view model class like this:

```
public class ToDoViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ToDo> Todos{ get; set; }
    public ToDo NewToDoItem { get; set; } 
}
```

Then change your contoller's action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var todoViewModel = new ToDoViewModel(); 
     todoViewModel.NewToDoItem = new Todo();
     todoViewModel.Todos= db.Todos.ToList(); 
     return View(todoViewModel);
}
```

And then adjust your Index view:

```
@model ToDoMVC.Models.ToDoViewModel
@RenderPage("~/Views/Todo/Create.cshtml",Model.NewToDoItem)
```

Comment: In that case my purpose will not be solved. I want to use different models, to make my app more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a MasterModel and refer it to index view

```
public Class MasterModel
{
   Public IEnumerable<ToDo> TodoList { get; set; }
   Public ToDo CreateModel { get; set; }  
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
       MasterModel model = new MasterModel();
       model.CreateModel = new Todo();
       model.TodoList  = db.Todos.ToList();
       return View(model );
 }
```

Refer this to Index model

```
@model MasterModel   
@RenderPage("~/Views/Todo/Create.cshtml",Model.CreateModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

A view inside a view or inother words, a `nested view`  is not viable as far as my affair with MVC goes. You create a view and bind it to a model to show data relevant to that model on the browser. Now if you want data from other multiple models / business entities to be rendered on the view then you use ViewModels ([Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc),[Reference 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553944/asp-net-mvc-3-viewmodel-pattern) and for that matter, the answers above remain valid. You can also customize / define `sections` on your layout to render specific information aswell. `Partial views` also make an option depending on the kind of info you want delivered to the view.